# Is there a way to delete GitHub forked repositories in bulk?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to delete forked repositories on GitHub in bulk?

The GitHub UI only allows me to delete one at a time. I fork projects often to make PRs and it will be time-consuming to only be able to delete one repository at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Github has an excellent API for doing so.

GitHub API : https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository
Pass the `DELETE` command with your repo link

```
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -XDELETE https://api.github.com/repos/<YOUR REPO NAME>
```